# Upgrading to Rails 3.2.8 causes stack level too deep error with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am fairly new to Ruby however I am running into an issue which I am having trouble getting to the bottom of.

My simple application was working fine and then, after upgrading the Rails version to 3.2.8 I hit an issue when trying to query my database for records. This works fine when using Rails 3.0.7 but after upgrading to rails 3.2.8 it starts to fail with a Stack Level too deep error.

My model looks like this:

```
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base 
  validates :title, :presence => true, 
                    :length => { :minimum => 5} 
  validates :link,  :presence => true 
  validates :date_submitted,  :presence => true 

  has_many :comments 

  validates_format_of :link, :with => URI::regexp(%w(http https)) 
  validates :link, :uniqueness => {:scope => :link, :message => "This item has already been submitted"} 
end
```

And when I call Resource.all from the console this fails with the following error:

> SystemStackError: stack level too deep    from
>   /home/tom/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/workspace.rb:80
>   Maybe IRB bug!!

It also seems to happen with other models as well and the fact this worked fine before the upgrade seems to suggest it is something else. Does anyone have any ideas of where I should be looking - the error information is quite limited.

UPDATE: after doing a little more digging this seems to start to break when changing to Rails 3.2.1. Rails 3.2.0 and less - my application works fine - 3.2.1 or greater causes the stack level too deep issue.

UPDATE 2: Found the issue. I was using the [SearchLogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) gem which was causing the issue. Removing that from the GemFile solved my problems.

Comment: hey, Tom. Is it possible to push this app to github? Also you can create a simple app that reproduces this issue. Thanks!

Comment: From a standard running rails app (i.e. not in a consol) do you have issues calling `Resource.all`?  In either case, could you execute with tracer enabled and post the additional error details, in the case of irb `irb --tracer`should do it.

Comment: You can see the list of changes between `3.2.0` and `3.2.1` **[here](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v3.2.0...v3.2.1)**

Comment: I'd also try commenting out the `has_many`, as well as renaming the model temporarily in case the name `Resource` is conflicting with some gem's definition of `Resource`.

Comment: I tried commenting out the has_many and also renaming the Resource model to Resource1 but to no avail. Having a look though the change list now.

Comment: also - I have the same issue whether through the console or when trying to run the application using WebBrick. I tried running the console with the debugger but just the same error.

Comment: Can you try removing the `:scope => link` from your uniqueness validation? I don't think that you want that in there anyway.

Comment: Never mind - found the issue. I was using the SearchLogic gem which was causing the issue. Removing that from the GemFile solved my problems. Only took several hours to figure it out - at least I think I understand how things work a little better now. Thanks for the suggestions.